# Dealing with trailing slashes in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

There's quite a bit of content available on mod_rewrite but I simply haven't been able to get the following to work.

Right now I have the following code in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
Options -Multiviews
ErrorDocument 400 http://localhost/mywebsite/400.php
ErrorDocument 403 http://localhost/mywebsite/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/mywebsite/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 http://localhost/mywebsite/500.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Which will succesfully make things like mywebsite/index work(instead of mywebsite/index.php).
However there are some situations where I will have visitors who will access the site with a trailing slash(mywebsite/index/) and then my rewrite no longer functions. and I receive an error page.

So how will I make it work so any page with either a trailing slash, no slash, or an extension(.php) will work on my website?

I will add that this is on localhost on an apache server(XAMPP) in case this affects how mod_rewrite works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code with this :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: This made both URLs with trailing slashes and without malfunction(only urls with extensions work after using this)

Comment: Gave me a 404 error page. The fact that it doesn't work makes me wonder if I missed a setting in the apache server, which would be extremely strange since the original code worked fine for anything but trailing spaces.

Comment: @Bucketman I think mod-rewrite is not reading the value of your %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} Correctly, You can replace **%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}** With your document root To test this example ,ie : var/www/etc

Comment: Alright I've found the problem. DOCUMENT ROOT is not the same as project root(probably due to xampp settings). `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/mywebsite/$1.php` worked! Unfortunately now it no longer loads the css but at least I can move on now. thanks all the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Because you can't test before if file (without /) exist or not.

Comment: I still got an error 500 page when trying to use `mywebsite/index/` with a trailing slash. If relevant I will add that this is on localhost, just in case that affects it.

Answer (score 0):

A rewrite rule like this should do the trick:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: I replaced my RewriteRule with yours but the trailing slash still gives me an error 500 page.

Comment: What do your logs say the 500 error is caused by? That you're not getting a 404 makes me think something else is going on.

Comment: [core:error] [pid 10648:tid 1840] [client ::1:17180] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.